# Asp .net MVC is working when I run it locally but I get internal network error when I deploy to azure web apps?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am having an internal server error immediately when I deploy my code to Azure web apps even though it runs perfectly fine on my own machine. My code is from a tutorial and close to this example:
https://github.com/elishnevsky/OdeToFood/tree/master/src/OdeToFood

However I do not have a web.config or an OdeToFood.xproj since they are not included in the tutorial. I tried including the ones that are in this git project but the error doesn't change. I ensured the permissions were configured to allow everyone to have full control.

My project is connected to a remote database that I can successfully connect to and manipulate from my local machine.

I have gone into the azure diagnostic tools and turned all the logging options on, however the error message being shown in the log stream doesn't change.
The error can be seen below.

I have tried including a random image to counter the favicon.ico error but that did not change anything.

Can anyone advise on some debugging tips, I think I need an idea on how to get a verbose error message.

IIS Detailed Error - 500.0 - Internal Server Error

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Most likely causes:

- IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during
  the processing of the request.
- The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the
  request and what was happening in the worker process when this error
  occurred.
- IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or
  application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set
  incorrectly.
- IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or
  application. The authenticated user does not have permission to use
  this DLL.
- The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility
  Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:

- Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct
  and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
- Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
  Verify the permissions for the DLL.
- Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a
  managed handler.
- Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status
  code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed
  requests, click here.

---

Detailed Error Information: Module   AspNetCoreModule Notification   ExecuteRequestHandler Handler   aspNetCore Error Code   0x00000000 Requested URL   http://OdeToFood20170518102616:80/ Physical Path   D:\home\site\wwwroot Logon Method   Anonymous Logon User   Anonymous
More Information: This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.
Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

IIS Detailed Error - 500.0 - Internal Server Error

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Most likely causes:

IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request.

The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.
Things you can try:
Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
Verify the permissions for the DLL.
Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click.
Detailed Error Information: Module   AspNetCoreModule Notification   ExecuteRequestHandler Handler   aspNetCore Error Code   0x00000000 Requested URL   OdeToFood20170518102616:80/favicon.ico Physical Path   D:\home\site\wwwroot\favicon.ico Logon Method   Anonymous Logon User   Anonymous
More Information: This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.
Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

Comment: Problem solved, Copied over node_modules folder as below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your github project, I have crate a test demo on my computer. I found this project has define a custom Physical File Provider (You could find 
 the it in the Middleware folder: UseNodeModules).

By cloning the project to the local, VS will automatic download the js file into the node_modules folder.

When publishing the project to azure web app service, the VS will not copy the node_modules folder to the azure web app. So the application will how 500 error.

I suggest you could find the UseNodeModules folder in the local and copy it to the azure web application.

More details, you could refer to below steps.

1.Open the KUDU console in your web app.

[image]

2.CLick CMD console and local the wwwrot folder

[image]

3.Add new folder and upload the node_modules folder.

[image]

Restart the application, them your project will work well.

> Since your project isn't as same as the github projects, if you still get the mistake.

I suggest you could change the application setting as below to see the details error message.

1.Open application setting in your web service portal.

[image]

2.Add Hosting:Environment as below:

[image]

Besides, I suggest you could check your web application's connection string. Azure web app couldn't connect to the local server if you don't use Hybrid connections.

I suggest you could create a azure sql server and change the connection string as azure sql server's connection string.

Comment: Thank you! You were 100% right about copying the node_modules over. Once I created a directory in the wwwroot folder I copied over the files I was using for bootstrap and it worked immediately. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: I'm glade that my answer help you solved the issue. If you feel my answer is useful /helpful. Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.